# Intentional duplicate questions for searchability

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I believe we need the question "Where can I buy a Raspberry Pi?", but it's already well covered by [Which distributors are authorized to sell device units?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3/68) since they aren't readily available by unauthorised retailers.

If we want this site to be found from Google, I believe it's important to have the duplicate question asked, even if we close it immediately as a duplicate.

I've gone ahead and [created the question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/112/68), but since it's likely to be worth of discussion, I'll link the question to this meta question as a starting point for discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please don't intentionally post duplicate questions as a method of bookkeeping or to *link juice* Google. You'll have enough trouble keeping up with them when duplicates happen organically. The proper course of action is to improve the *original* question to make it easier to find.

From the blog post:

[**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

> “What is the single most important design element of a new Q&A site?” The answer is obviously, “The questions on the front page.”

… and posting closed questions just creates a crap-fest for people coming to visit this site for the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have a question that covers every different way people are going to try asking it.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, but take your reasoning out of the question, I'd say. That way, when it is found by some Googler, they don't get confused by the semantics of the way we operate.

Comment: So basically, reduce it down to a simple question, and keep the traditional `Q&A` format